#  Brightness setting is reset to maximum at login

Tags: 12.04, brightness

My laptop's screen brightness is auto set to maximum at login (= at the login screen already).

Even after I have adjusted it to lower it is again set to maximum after annother login. Is there a way to save the previous brightness settings in Ubuntu 12.04?

#### Additional Info by gentmatt:

This definitely seems to be related to the used graphics.

- When using the **discrete** graphics, the brightness is set to maximum on every boot.
- When using the **integrated** graphics, the brightness setting which **Mac OS X has set** is used.

  But **Ubuntu does not change** that setting. It uses the stored setting by OS X. Therefore, the brightness at login is only changed, when OS X changes the brightness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution:
Add

```
xbacklight -set 80
```

to the file

```
.xinitrc
```

This will set the backlight to the desired value (80) whenever `X` is started.
`.xinitrc` is the configuration file responsible for the X-Server.

Answer (score 3):

Some laptop's have that setting in the bios, like this: [image: example]

You normally press the Del or F2 button during startup to get into the bios, the key is written on the first screen you see when your computer starts.

But I'm not sure if you can change these settings from ubuntu.

Comment: I'm having this problem on a Macbook Pro.